# Move y-axis in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I wanted to get my plot to look like this:

[image]

I would like to get some help to move the y-axis to x=0.  Thanks for your help and time.  Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin = 0, axis x line = bottom, axis y line=left, legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot [domain=-5:5,cyan, thick]{x^2 + 2*x + 2};
\addplot [domain=0:10,orange,thick]{2*x + 2};
\legend{$f(x)$, $g(x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `axis` options, just change the `axis y line` from `left` to `middle`:

```
axis y line = middle
```

Your plot becomes:

[image: Output]

Comment: How do you extend the x-axis line out and print the "x" label on the end (like that shown in the graphic)?  Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: @Joe you may post a new question and link to here. This site has its own page for each question, unlike a discussion forum.